# By default the for loop is iterating for the first time with out taking the string input?

Tags: java

```
       public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
           int i;
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter No :");
           int num =sc.nextInt();

           System.out.println(""+num);
           for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
            {
             System.out.println("Enter  : ");
             String line=sc.nextLine();
             //StringBuilder line1=fun(line);

             System.out.println("THE no is: "+line1);
            }


         }
        catch (Exception e)
         {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Here after giving the no  the loop is iterating for the first time without 
    taking the string input . How can I take the string  input  in each iteration.

Comment: I think there's still an unconsumed end-of-line after your integer input.

Comment: where is `try` block?

Comment: `int num = Integer.parseInt(sc.next())`; This will work for you.